# how to use xrandr tool for dual screen

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I'm  working on Raspberry 2B with Raspbian Strech. I plugged a USB /  DVI adaptator which is listed in the lsub command :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
.../...
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 17e9:4301 DisplayLink 
..../...
```

I installed the DispalyLink driver version 4.4.24 [from here](https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu) The last version doesn't work. I've got these library errors :

```
~# : sudo /opt/displaylink/DisplayLinkManager 
./DisplayLinkManager: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by ./DisplayLinkManager)
./DisplayLinkManager: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.25' not found (required by ./DisplayLinkManager)
./DisplayLinkManager: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.11' not found (required by ./DisplayLinkManager)
./DisplayLinkManager: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by ./DisplayLinkManager)
~# : strings /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6 |grep GLIBC
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.15
GLIBC_2.18
GLIBC_2.23
GLIBC_2.24
GLIBC_PRIVATE
```

In according this procedure : 
https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1883065-using-arm-binaries-on-raspbian-on-raspberry-pi

and using the driver version 4.4.24 I've to use these commands :

```
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0
xrandr --listproviders
```

After theses commands I can see the both monitor in the xrandr list. After that,  I can apply xrandr configuration as dual screen but the screen which is connected on the USB device is frozen. 
So I apply the lightdm restart : `sudo service lightdm restart`

Only the monitor which is connected in USB still up and running the other one which is connected on the HDMI is switched off. 
I've to restart the Raspberry board for get the HDMI port working.

Comment: xrandr can only trigger video detection, list what it finds, and change settings, it can't fix a broken driver.  You need to get the driver working before xrandr is of any help.

Comment: The library errors indicate a version mismatch.   You probably have a driver for a different version of the OS.