# USB Dual Monitor DisplayLink Docking Station for Pi 4 B? I have WAVLink UG39DKx docking stations

Tags: raspbian, display, pi-4, screen, peripherals

- My WavLink UG39DKx docking stations are USB 3.0, have an HDMI and DVI out, plus 2 USB 3.0 and 4 USB 2.0, plus Ethernet, plus Audio out.
- Is there a reasonable way to get the docking station working?
- If this particular dock won't work, is there something similar I can buy?  The only "docking stations" I saw in the https://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals list looked to be USB devices that held only 2 disks, not monitors, Ethernet, etc.
- I already move 2 Windows PCs back and forth (switch which machine is connected, or use the Dock at my other office, etc.), but I was wondering, since the dock has two monitors, keyboard and mouse, and wired headset connected, if there is a way to get it working with Raspbian.
- I have kernel 4.19.75 running.
- I tried following the instructions at https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu but my system still only sees the HDMI connection to the first monitor, it doesn't see the monitor that is still connected to the Docking station.
- lsusb does see additional devices when I plug in the docking station, but I couldn't use a mouse attached through it, I can only use the mouse that is directly attached to the USB 2.0 port of the Pi 4B.
- I also looked at the answer at [how to use xrandr tool for dual screen](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/94650/how-to-use-xrandr-tool-for-dual-screen) but I don't really understand the answer and what it would mean to my situation.
- I suppose I could drop a 4 port Gigabit switch in, use an HDMI-to-DVI-D adapter when I want the monitor on the docking station, and my two monitors on HDMI cables to my Pi, and put my keyboard and mouse and webcam on a USB 3.0 hub, but I'd rather go with the more elegant solution of having a docking station that works.  Heck, if there was a dock out there that had selectable USB inputs so that I didn't have to move the USB cable back and forth that would be even better!
- Admittedly, I am somewhat newish to Linux, mostly meaning that my unix/linux experience isn't deep or particularly recent, though I am an IT professional who has used *nix occasionally since XENIX in the 1980s.

Comment: why is the `3 WAVLink UG39DK docking stations in 2 different buildings` important? ... it appears to be unnecessary clutter in your post